# Airflow XCOM pull is not rendering

Tags: python, jinja2, airflow

I have a custom operator where in the argument list I am using xcom_pull to get values from XCOM. But it is not rendering to actual value instead it remains as the string.

```
download= CustomSparkSubmitOperator(
    task_id='download',
    spark_args=command_func(
        env, application,
        '%s/spark_args' % key,
        ['--input_file', "{{ ti.xcom_pull('set_parameters', key='input_file') }}",
         '--output_file', "{{ ti.xcom_pull('set_parameters', key='output_file') }}"
         ],
    provide_context=True,
    dag=dag)
```

The operator returns the following output:

`spark-submit --deploy-mode cluster .....  --input_file "{{ ti.xcom_pull('set_parameters', key='input_file') }}" --output_file "{{ ti.xcom_pull('set_parameters', key='output_file') }}"`

Comment: What are the `template_fields` for your custom Operator?

Comment: I dont have template_fields in custom Operator @JoshFell

Comment: Does the operator inherit from the `SparkSubmitOperator`, the `BaseOperator`, or another? Where I'm going is that not every parameter for operators, sensors, etc. have a value that can be Jinja templated.  Those parameters are explicitly called out as class attributes when creating the operator.  For example, check out the `template_fields` for the `SparkSubmitOperator`: [https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/providers/apache/spark/operators/spark_submit.py](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/providers/apache/spark/operators/spark_submit.py)

Comment: I added this line template_fields = ('args') to the first line to the operator, the task does not even start. It is just struck

Comment: You need an ending comma for that value to be a tuple: `template_fields = (args,)`. When you say the task is stuck, is there an exception thrown or does the task execute and not progress?  Also, I'd highly recommend not calling a function when instantiating the operator or as top-level code in a DAG.  Top-level code will be execute every time the DAG file is parsed which could be very frequently depending on your environment configuration and could lead to performance degradation.

Comment: Yes I agree on the part of not to have the function call when instantiating the operator. It causes degradation

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix the problem of XCOM values not rendering when using as an argument in my CustomSparkSubmitEMROperator. Internally the operator inherits the EMROperators. For example

`class CustomSparkSubmitEMROperator(EmrAddStepsOperator, EmrStepSensor):`

So I needed to add the below template_fields as shown below

```
template_fields = ('job_flow_id', 'steps')
```

After adding the above lines the XCOM values where properly rendered and was able to see the correct values in the resultant spark-submit command